# connecting 2 or more virtualbox vm's to the internet without connecting them to each other / or to the host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to build a lab environment, for testing an openVPN network between a 2~3 virtual machines. In order to do so, I want to setup the connections (virtualbox network adapter) of each VM to connect the internet, in such a way that the VM's have distinct ip's, and they cannot access each other on the local network / host computer.

I thought about connecting each VM to a public VPN service such privateVpn service (provided by OpenVPN.net) and other similar services, but I wonder if that's not an overkill... All I want is the VM's to simulate different computers, running in different networks, shouldn't there be a way of configuring the virtualbox to do so without additional effort?

As the unprofessional network specialist I am :) I find the different virtualbox networking solutions a bit too complex for my brain.. So, I hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system is running on the host computer?

Comment: I am using ubuntu host for one VM and win64 for other two VMs

Comment: What do you mean by *running in different networks*? If the pcs are connected to your LAN, they cannot be on different networks.

Comment: I am trying to **simulate** computers connected to the internet from different places (as if there's no local area network between them). I want to so, so I can later build an openvpn network between the vm's, and re-connect them, for test/dev purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 links handling my **exact** setup :) leading to 2 virtual router products that solved my problem:

www.danscourses.com/Network-Security/create-a-virtual-network-with-virtual-routerfirewall.html
theithollow.com/2012/04/virtual-routing-for-bubble-networks/

And the products used (in respective order):

[Endian Firewall](http://www.endian.com/us/community/download/#.UsiTdrRDdfd)

[Vyatta Virtual Router](http://www.vyatta.org/downloads)

Seems that virtual router is the thing that I was looking for...